# 500 "Internal Server Error" with ajax in Joomla

Tags: php, ajax, joomla

I'm using Ajax at front-end joomla site but unfortunately it doesn't run. Here is my code:

/components/com_prova/js/dashboard.js

```
$.ajax({
        url: "index.php?option=com_prova&task=ajaxraw.updateReserve&format=raw",
        data: { robotId: idRobot, reserved: book}
          }).done(function(response) {
              console.log(response);
    });
```

/components/com_prova/controllers/ajaxraw.php

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die( 'Restricted access' );
jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');
jimport('functions.php');
class MycomponentControllerAjaxraw extends JController
{
     function updateReserve(){

     $booked = JRequest::getVar('reserved');
     $robotId = JRequest::getVar('robotId');

     $db_external=db_ext();

     $query = $db_external->getQuery(true);         
     $query = 'UPDATE robots SET booked='.$booked.' WHERE id='.$robotId;    

     $db_external->setQuery($query);
     $db_external->query();
}
}
?>
```

I get this error:

```
 jquery-1.12.3.min.js:4 GET http://xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/index.php?option=com_prova&task=ajaxraw.updateReserve&format=raw&robotId=1&reserved=1&lang=it 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

I have read different posts about that, but nothing works....help please!

**UPDATE**

```
function db_ext(){

$option = array(); 

$option['driver']   = 'mysql';            // Database driver name
$option['host']     = 'xxxxxx';                 // Database host name
$option['user']     = 'xxxxxxx';   // User for database authentication
$option['password'] = 'xxxxxxxx';     // Password for database authentication
$option['database'] = 'xxxxxxxxx';   // Database name
$option['prefix']   = '';                 // Database prefix (may be empty)
$db_external = &JDatabase::getInstance( $option );
return $db_external;
}
```

**UPDATE DEBUG**

If I go to

index.php?option=com_prova&task=ajaxraw.updateReserve&format=raw&robotId=2&reserved=1&lang=en

I have this error

```
Invalid controller: name='ajaxraw', format='raw'
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: `Request` is deprecated. Please use [JInput](http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput). You should also be using [Joomla's API properly](http://docs.joomla.org/Inserting,_Updating_and_Removing_data_using_JDatabase) for your database query

Comment: What's in `index.php`? That file appears to be generating the 500 error.

Comment: @Marcus - `index.php` is Joomla's core file where the application gets executed from. That won't be the issue ;)

Comment: @Lodder the input method is not a problem. I have tried also $_REQUEST but the problem is the same. I have updated the post with the db_ext() function

Comment: @Marcus Lodder is right, the problem is not in index.php :(

Comment: I would suggest removing the Ajax for the time being and just stick to PHP so you can see all errors. So, comment out all the Ajax code, then go to your Global Configuration and set **Error Reporting** to `development`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code I've fixed up for you will not be the solid solution but will push you in the right direction as there's currently a lot wrong with your code as it stands:

- Incorrect use of API
- Deprecated functions
- Incorrect approach for calling functions

Comment out all your Ajax code and let's just try and get some results show just with PHP:

```
class MycomponentControllerAjaxraw extends JController
{
    public function updateReserve()
    {
        $input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;

        $booked  = $input->get('reserved', '', 'INT');
        $robotId = $input->get('robotId', '', 'INT');

        $db = $this->external_db();

        $query = $db->getQuery(true);

        $fields = array(
            $db->quoteName('booked') . ' = ' . (int)$booked
        );

        $conditions = array(
            $db->quoteName('id') . ' = ' . (int)$robotId
        );

        $query->update($db->quoteName('robots'))->set($fields)->where($conditions);

        $db->setQuery($query);

        $result = $db->execute();
    }

    private function external_db()
    {
        $option = array();

        $option['driver']   = 'mysql';
        $option['host']     = 'xxx';
        $option['user']     = 'xxx';
        $option['password'] = 'xxx';
        $option['database'] = 'xxx';
        $option['prefix']   = '';

        $db = JDatabaseDriver::getInstance($option);

        return $db;
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, but if I comment out all the ajax, I have to use the post method, reloading the page. What do I call? How can I call the controller method?